# redux-thunk: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

Trying to create a simple CRUD app using an API. I've got Login and Register working, so I know redux-thunk is set up in the store properly.

I've seen lots of similar questions, but none of the answer have fixed my issue. I know the dispatches are supposed to return functions. I'm pretty sure that is the case. I'm new to react and a little lost on how to debug. Console.log is not showing anything, so I've used alerts. I'm happy to provide any additional information. Thx for looking.

Error

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
  20 |  componentDidMount() {
  21 |    const { dispatch } = this.props;
  22 |    const { error, rosterMembers, isFetching } = this.props;
  23 |    dispatch(rosterActions.getAll());
  24 | 
  25 |  }
  26 |
```

Container: RosterListCard.js

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {Card, CardBody, Col, ButtonToolbar} from 'reactstrap';
import EmailIcon from 'mdi-react/EmailIcon'
import CheckboxMarkedCircleIcon from 'mdi-react/CheckboxMarkedCircleIcon'
import AlertCircleIcon from 'mdi-react/AlertCircleIcon'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import { rosterActions } from '../../../../redux/actions';

class RosterListCard extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
//    this.getNoRowsRenderer = this.getNoRowsRenderer.bind(this);
//    this.getRowClassName = this.getRowClassName.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const { error, rosterMembers, isFetching } = this.props;
    dispatch(rosterActions.getAll());

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { dispatch } = nextProps;
    dispatch(rosterActions.getAll());
  }

  getNoRowsRenderer() {
    return (
      <div className="noRows">
        No rows
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { error, rosterMembers, isFetching } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {console.log(error)}
        {console.log(isFetching)}
        {console.log(rosterMembers)}
        {error &&
          <div className="alert alert-danger">
            {error.message || "Unknown errors."}
          </div>}
        {!isFetching &&
          rosterMembers.length === 0 &&
          <div className="alert alert-warning">Oops, nothing to show.</div>}

        {rosterMembers &&

          <Table striped>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Title</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.props.rosterMembers.map((rosterMember) => (
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{rosterMember.fullName}</th>
                  <td>{rosterMembers.title}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

RosterListCard.propTypes = {
  rosterMembers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.object,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps (state) {

  return {
    error: null,
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    totalCount: 0,
    rosterMembers: []
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RosterListCard);
```

Actions: roster.actions.js

```
import { sessionService } from 'redux-react-session';
import { rosterConstants } from '../constants';
import { callApi } from "../../utilities/api.utility.js";

export const rosterActions = {
  getAll
};

function rosterRequest() {
  return {
    type: rosterConstants.GETALL_REQUEST
  };
}


function rosterSuccess() {
  return function(payload) {
    return {
      type: rosterConstants.GETALL_SUCCESS,
      rosterMembers: payload.items,
      totalCount: payload.total_count
    };
  };
}

function rosterFailure() {
  return function(error) {
    return {
      type: rosterConstants.GETALL_FAILURE,
      error
    };
  };
}

export function getAll() {
  sessionService.loadSession()
    .then(session => {
//      if (typeof session.token === 'undefined') return rosterFailure();
      const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/Rosters?access_token=${session.token}`;
      return callApi(
        url,
        null,
        rosterRequest(),
        rosterSuccess(),
        rosterFailure()
      )
    });
}
```

API module: api.utility.js

```
import "isomorphic-fetch";

export function checkStatus(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    // (response.status < 200 || response.status > 300)
    const error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }
  return response;
}

export function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}

/**
 * A utility to call a restful service.
 *
 * @param url The restful service end point.
 * @param config The config object of the call. Can be null.
 * @param request The request action.
 * @param onRequestSuccess The callback function to create request success action.
 *                 The function expects response json payload as its argument.
 * @param onRequestFailure The callback function to create request failure action.
 *                 The function expects error as its argument.
 */
export function callApi(
  url,
  config,
  request,
  onRequestSuccess,
  onRequestFailure
) {
  alert('request');
  return dispatch => {
    alert('request***');
    dispatch(request);
    return fetch(url, config)
      .then(checkStatus)
      .then(parseJSON)
      .then(json => {
        alert('request***');
        dispatch(onRequestSuccess(json));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert('request***');
        const response = error.response;
        if (response === undefined) {
          dispatch(onRequestFailure(error));
        } else {
          error.status = response.status;
          error.statusText = response.statusText;
          response.text().then(text => {
            try {
              const json = JSON.parse(text);
              error.message = json.message;
            } catch (ex) {
              error.message = text;
            }
            dispatch(onRequestFailure(error));
          });
        }
      });
  };
  alert('request end');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `redux-thunk`, then your async "action creators" should look something like:

```
export function getAll() {
  return dispatch => {
      sessionService.loadSession()
          .then(session => {
              if (typeof session.token === 'undefined') return dispatch(rosterFailure());
              const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/Rosters?access_token=${session.token}`;
              dispatch(rosterRequest());
              fetch(url, config).then(response => {
                  // validate response and convert to JSON
                  dispatch(rosterSuccess(json));
              }
           }).catch(err => {
              // Handle/Transform error
              dispatch(rosterFailure(err));
           }
         });
  }
}
```

Also, I think you're missing some details about `redux-thunk`. The actions that asynchronously `dispatch` other actions should return functions (where `dispatch` is the first and only required argument). Other actions should just return typical action objects with a `type` and any other information the reducer function will need to update it's store.

For example, your `rosterRequest` looks exactly as I'd expect, but `rosterSuccess` should look something like:

```
function rosterSuccess(paylod) {
  return {
    type: rosterConstants.GETALL_SUCCESS,
    rosterMembers: payload.items,
    totalCount: payload.total_count
  };
}
```

Then, you can `mapDispatchToProps` when you `connect` your component instead of expecting the component to directly have a `dispatch` prop.

For example, at the bottom of `RosterListCard.js`:

```
RosterListCard.propTypes = {
  rosterMembers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.object,
  getAllRoster: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps (state) {

  return {
    error: null,
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false,
    totalCount: 0,
    rosterMembers: []
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getAllRoster: rosterActions.getAll
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RosterListCard);
```

And you could call that function from `this.props` whenever you need to:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { error, rosterMembers, isFetching } = this.props;
    this.props.getAllRoster();
}
```